# Moving from weekly to daily data in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date

Hi I have some weekly data in a dataframe

```
data = {'dates': ['03-01-2020', '10-01-2020', '17-01-2020', '24-01-2020'], 'total': [1,2, 3, 4]}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I would like to turn it into daily data - I.e. have an entry for each date and copy the total from the first day of the week onto every day of the week.

Notably the data i'm working with has many months worth of entries. So I'm trying to find a solution that wont get buggy around the ends of months.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I think you need a way to reliably manipulate dates. Have you checked the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%m-%Y')    
df = df.set_index('dates').resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
print(df)

        dates  total
0  2020-01-03      1
1  2020-01-04      1
2  2020-01-05      1
3  2020-01-06      1
4  2020-01-07      1
5  2020-01-08      1
6  2020-01-09      1
7  2020-01-10      2
8  2020-01-11      2
9  2020-01-12      2
10 2020-01-13      2
11 2020-01-14      2
12 2020-01-15      2
13 2020-01-16      2
14 2020-01-17      3
15 2020-01-18      3
16 2020-01-19      3
17 2020-01-20      3
18 2020-01-21      3
19 2020-01-22      3
20 2020-01-23      3
21 2020-01-24      4
```